# Getting the value entered in the “Display text input” field of a picklist choice in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, screen-flow

I was looking for the simplest way, in a flow, to allow the user to pick either a value from a list of presets, or to type a custom value.
I noticed that I could configure one of the choices like this:

[image: choice config screenshot]

The resulting form looks like what I need:

[image: form screenshot]

… but I failed to find a way to get the entered value (“Plop” in the example above) in the later stages of the flow. It basically seems that no resource is created to store it, and using the choice itself as a resource yields my “Other (Please specify)” label string. The Picklist field resource itself yields that as well.

I may end up resorting to a manual “visibility rule” on an explicit extra input field, but I wish I could use a more built-in feature for this. In particular, I’d like to be able to get the value (regardless of it being a preset or a custom one) in one go, without extra steps trying to determine whether a custom value was used, etc.